# How does P-protein (phloem) help in sealing of wounds?

Tags: plant-physiology, plant-anatomy

While I was reading a book I found that "P-proteins in the sieve elements of phloem help in sealing  of wounds along with callose".

So how does p-protein do that, moreover how can it reach to other parts of plant body in order to seal the wounds?